# What database solution can I use for backbone app?

Tags: database, backbone.js, offline, indexeddb, phonegap

Could you help me with this problem?

I have a simple phonegap build web app that uses backbone.js and localstorage. I have encountered a problem when trying to add a new feature to my app. My app currently has a small database of 13 items, each of which have various attributes. These attributes are modified by user input and stored in local storage, allowing them to persist between app opening and closing.

I want to add a feature that will allow the user to add custom items, eg item 14, 15, 16. However, when I think about saving these items in local storage, they would be save as id=14, id=15, id=16. WHat happens then if a user deletes item 14, then wants to add item 17. The app will check the number of items (15 in total (items 1-13, plus items 15 and 16)), then try to save item 17 as item 16. Item 16 will already exist in the database!

I'm sure that I've used localstorage incorrectly and I should have used a different storage solution from the start.

Is there a way to code a solution to this and keep my existing localstorage solution, or will I need to move to a different storage solution such as indexeddb or websql. I am an amateur developer so if you could explain it to me as best you can I would be very grateful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help. The issue is specifically in the sentence "The app will check the number of items (15 in total (items 1-13, plus items 15 and 16)), then try to save item 17 as item 16." You have two purposes in play. One is to count the number of items. The second is to decide on what should be the id of a new item. Right now you state you are setting the id of a new item based on the count of existing items plus one.

You can change your thinking about this by recognizing the two purposes, and separating them. First, you can keep the count of items function, but recognize that its only purpose is to get a count of things. Second, you can use a different strategy for setting a new item id.

There are lots of strategies available to you. One would be this: a number that only ever increases. Each time an item is added it increases. When an item is deleted, this number does not decrease. This number is not a count of items, it is just a continuously incrementing number.

Save the current value of this continuously incrementing number in local storage.

When you create a new item, increment the number, use the incremented number as the id of the new item, and then also update the new value of the number in local storage.

Then the only thing you ever have to worry about is whether over the lifetime of your program will actually create 2 billion items, and have the number end up being as high as it can possibly be, to the point where you cannot add 1 to it anymore. Probably unlikely.